# R: Nested data problems: data frame with list columns issue

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested

My general issue is that I need to separate multiple columns with nested lists together with data from the other columns. It's probably easier to show the structure:

```
Var1         Var2        Var3            Var4
"BCD"        "123"   c("A, B, C")    c("T, U, V")
"GFV"        "125"   c("A, B, D")    c("L, C, A")
```

What I need to get:

```
Var1         Var2        Var3            Var4
"BCD"        "123"       A               T
"BCD"        "123"       B               U
"BCD"        "123"       C               V       
"GFV"        "125"       A               L
"GFV"        "125"       B               C
"GFV"        "125"       D               A
```

I've tried several solutions but none exactly work as expected. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide data with `dput(head(df,n))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `unnest`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  unnest(cols = c(Var3, Var4))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4 
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 BCD   123   A     T    
#2 BCD   123   B     U    
#3 BCD   123   C     V    
#4 GFV   125   A     L    
#5 GFV   125   B     C    
#6 GFV   125   D     A
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c("BCD", "GFV"), Var2 = c("123", "125"), 
    Var3 = structure(list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("A", "B", "D")),
      class = "AsIs"), 
    Var4 = structure(list(c("T", "U", "V"), c("L", "C", "A")),
  class = "AsIs")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

`strsplit` can be used to split strings into vector/list and by default `data.frame` will repeat other variables and strech

```
data.frame(x$var1, x$var2,
       var3 = unlist(strsplit(x$var3,",")),
       var4 = unlist(strsplit(x$var4,",")))
```

**Result**

```
 x <- data.frame(var1=c("BCD","GFV"), var2=c("123","125"), var3=c("A,B,C","A,B,D"), var4 = c("T,U,V","L,C,A"),stringsAsFactors=F)
  x.var1 x.var2 var3 var4

1    BCD    123    A    T
2    GFV    125    B    U
3    BCD    123    C    V
4    GFV    125    A    L
5    BCD    123    B    C
6    GFV    125    C    A
```